# YAML: Is it possible to have a list in the root section?

Tags: file, yaml

Is it possible to have a list in the root section of an YAML file?
So far I've seen no files that follow such a structure and I've been asking myself whether it violates the syntax.

Here is an example:

```
- 'entry A'
- 'entry B'
- 'entry C'
```

What I've seen so far:

```
list:
  - 'entry A'
  - 'entry B'
  - 'entry C'
```

So in other words, is the `list:` section obsolete?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**It's ok to do that.**
Here is a Java sample which use snakeYaml:

```java
Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
Object o = yaml.load("- 'entry A'\n- 'entry B'\n- 'entry C'");
System.out.println(o.getClass().getName());
```

The output of the code is `java.util.ArrayList`.

But in a real scenario, we store an object's content into a YAML file. When we do that, if the type of one field is a list, we actually store it in the way as you always see:

```yaml
field-name:
- item1
- item2
```

Answer (score 8):

No the the scalar `list` is not obsolete, it defines a completely different structure.

YAML files consist of *mappings*, *sequences* and *scalars*.

- A mapping consists of key-value pairs. A key can be scalars or a list; a value can be a mapping or a sequence or a scalar.
- A list consists of elements and each element can be a mapping, a sequence or a scalar
- A scalar is in principle a string, but certain strings can be interpreted specially ( numbers only -> integers, "False" -> boolean, etc.)

At the top level you can have a (single) scalar (admittedly this is not very flexible):

```
Hello world
```

or a mapping:

```
abc: 
  - 1
  - 2
```

or a a list:

```
- 1
- 2
```

Your first example has at the top level a sequence consisting of scalars, your second example has at the top level a mapping with a single key-value pair. The key being the scalar `list` and value being a sequence of scalars.